# Динамическое изменение value в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующая конструкция

```html
<div id="containerRange">
<div id="sliderRange"></div>

<span class="rangeValue">
    <span class="span_max">2</span> - <span class="jash_span_min">123</span>
</span>

<div class="row flex-input">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="number" value="2" class="form-control input_min" />     <input type="number" value="123" class="form-control input_max" />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Где

1. #sliderRange - Ползунок c двумя значениями - min и max
2. .rangeValue - два span элемента куда динамически передается положение ползунка
3. input[type="number"] - два поля ввода

Логика работы данной схемы следующая:

1. При смене положения ползунка **динамически** меняется значение в поле span, и загружаются продукты (согласно критериям) и только тогда изменяется значение в input[type="number"];
2. При изменении значения в input[type="number"] -> загружаются продукты (согласно критериям), изменяется положение ползунка и изменяется значение в span.

Все работает хорошо, если б не одно **НО**

- как сделать так, чтобы при смене положения ползунка изменялось **динамически** значение value в input[type="number"].

Пробовал реализовать так

```
$('#containerRange').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
    $(this).find('input.input_min').val($(this).find('.span_min').text());
    $(this).find('input.input_max').val($(this).find('.span_max').text());
});
```

Данные получаю из span но смена value не происходит

Буду благодарен в помощи, как можно реализовать такое поведение input

Comment: @klifort без демонстрации работы ползунка и кода отвечающего за его изменение - не получается воспроизвести вашу проблему, к примеру: `$('.span_max').click(function(){$('input.input_min').val($('.span_max').text());});` вполне работает

Comment: @Хацкер, тяжело перенести код, так как данные получаются переменно. Интересует как можно реализовать работу JS в такой способ как написано тут - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26202266/8661408, только в обратную сторону - когда данные входят в `span`, и уже от него в input.

Comment: @Хацкер, да так работает только при событию `click`, срабатывает загрузка даных и уже тогда изменение атрибута `value` в `input`

Answer (score 1):

Может кому понадобится решение.

Так как изменение в `input` можна внести через `click` решил использовать только событие нажатие кнопки мышки `mousedown`, далее через `DOMSubtreeModifier` отслеживать изменения в `span` и уже в этот момент производить смену `value`.

```js
$('body').on('mousedown', '.containerRange', function () {

    $('.rangeValue').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
        var valMin = $(this).find('.span_min').text();
        var valMax = $(this).find('.span_max').text();

        $(this).closest('.containerRange').find('input.input_min').val(valMax).attr('min', valMax).attr('max', valMin);
        $(this).closest('.containerRange').find('input.input_max').val(valMin).attr('min', valMax).attr('max', valMin);
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="containerRange">
<div id="sliderRange"></div>

<span class="rangeValue">
    <span class="span_max">2</span> - <span class="jash_span_min">123</span>
</span>

<div class="row flex-input">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="number" value="2" class="form-control input_min" />     <input type="number" value="123" class="form-control input_max" />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```